# Laravel throws invalid variable error updating indirect related table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Thought fairly new to Laravel I am developing an app for vehicle registration and payment. I have 3 tables among other and they are:

Vehicles (hasmany invoices)
Invoices (has many transactions with foreign key: vehicle_id)
and Transactions with foreign key: invoice_id

Now I have a written a code in my Transactioncontroller store method to store transaction details, update users table, invoice table and vehicle table simultaneously. Every thing works well except the invoice update where i get a error of Undefined Variable.

Below is the whole code

```
public function store1(Request $request, $invoice_id) {

        $invoice = Invoice::find($invoice_id);
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->added_on = Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $transaction->pay_ref = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
        $transaction->invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
        $transaction->paid_amount = $request->paid_amount;
        $transaction->paid_method = 'Wallet';
        $transaction->status = 1;
        $transaction->invoice()->associate($invoice);
        $transaction->save();


        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
    if (Auth::user()->amount < $request->paid_amount){
        Flash::error('insufficient Balance');
           return redirect(route('transactions.index'));     
        }

         $user->amount = Auth::user()->amount - $transaction->paid_amount;
         $user->update();

         $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($invoice_id);
         $invoice->status = 1;
         $invoice->update();

    $vehicle = Vehicle::where('vehicle_id', $vehicle_id)->first();
        $vehicle->status = 2;
        $vehicle->update();


        Flash::success('Transaction done successfully.');
        return redirect(route('transactions.index'));   
   }

   }
```

i am sure the problem is from this query:

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::where('vehicle_id', $vehicle_id)->first();
```

1. How do i get the system to identify the Vehicle record and update it considering that no direct relationship between Vehicle table and Transaction table except shared relationship with Invoice table.
2. Also How do i rearrange the above codes so that the Balance check with the IF statement, can run before Transaction is inserted. The way it is now, transaction can be inserted even with zero balance and it is not what i had in mind,

Comment: Where do you get `$vehicle_id`??

Comment: @A,A Norman the $vehicke_id is a field in imvoices table, but i have previously tried to use $id etc etc and none worked. Any idea of a better query?

Comment: its not the query, you never defined `$vehicle_id` in the current scope

Comment: Thanks Lagbox but how do i do that. Most of what you saw in the codes above i was following online video tutorials. Please rewrite the code for me.